# How to prove this definite integral does not depend on the parameter?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am working on some development formulas for surfaces and as a byproduct of abstract theory i get that:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1+\sin^2\theta}{(\cos^4\theta+(\gamma\cos^2\theta-\sin\theta)^2)^\frac{3}{4}}d\theta$$
is independent on the parameter $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$. I thought that there was something wrong with my calculations but actually turns out that using Mathematica that the value is somewhat near $5,24412$ independently on the $\gamma$ I plug in the calculation of the integral. Is there any way to verify that actually this is a constant by direct computations, complex analysis, or at least is this kind of integrals studied?

Edit:obviously differentiating in the integral does not help much

Comment: "obviously differentiating in the integral does not help much" - but why? This seems to be like one sure way to prove the independence

Comment: Mathematica really estimates the derivative to be close to $0$ for any value of $\gamma$ I have tried. Now how to prove that. Update: Not only estimates, directly asking it to integrate for general  $\gamma$ returns $0$

Comment: well differentiating just makes the integral more complicated and with that really does not seem to help. I am sure this is a costant by other means, and I was really surprised when this formula turned out.

Comment: I have changed the title to make it better reflect the question. I hope this question receives more attention

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put
\begin{equation*}
I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{1+\sin^2\theta}{(\cos^4\theta +(\gamma\cos^2\theta-\sin \theta)^2)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\, d\theta
\end{equation*}
If $x = \dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$,  $\, y = \gamma-x$ and $y = \sqrt{z}$ then
\begin{equation*}
dx = \dfrac{\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta}{\cos^3\theta}\, d\theta
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{gather*}
I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta}{\cos^3\theta\left(1 +\left(\gamma-\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\, d\theta = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(1 +\left(\gamma- x\right)^2\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\left(1 +y^2\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\, dy = \\[2ex]
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^{\frac{1}{2}-1}}{(1+z)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}}}\, dz = {\rm B}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 5.244115109
\end{gather*}
where ${\rm B}$ is the Beta function.

Comment: How did you guess the substitution? Very nice! (+1)

Comment: I'm not sure how JanG actually did it, but one way to come to this would be to remember that integrals of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-c) dx$ are independent of $c$, and attempt to express the integral in the question in this form where $c = \gamma$. The logical first step in doing so is to factor out powers of $\cos\theta$ from the denominator, which immediately suggests $x = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$.

Comment: I am glad to see that the computation was so easy (from the point of view of lenght), very cooi the guess of the change of variables. It seems it should work in the same way for different exponents of the determinant too.

Comment: Very well done, @JanG!

Comment: $@$Yuriy S. I had no deep thoughts. I moved $\cos^4\theta$ outside the bracket $(\qquad )^{\frac{3}{4}}$ and differentiated $\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta}$. Then I realized that the substitution $y = \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta}$ would work.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment.

I still think it may be helpful to consider the derivative (I use $x$ as integration variable).

$$J=\frac{d}{d \gamma} I(\gamma)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{(1+\sin^2 x)(\gamma ~\cos^2 x-\sin x) \cos^2 x~dx}{\left(\cos^4 x+(\gamma~ cos^2 x-\sin x)^2 \right)^{7/4}}$$

We need to prove $J \equiv 0$.

However, there's a stronger statement $^*$, which seems to be true numerically:

$$J_1=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\gamma (1+\sin^2 x)  \cos^4 x~dx}{\left(\cos^4 x+(\gamma~ cos^2 x-\sin x)^2 \right)^{7/4}}$$

$$J_2=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{(1+\sin^2 x)  \cos^2 x \sin x ~dx}{\left(\cos^4 x+(\gamma~ cos^2 x-\sin x)^2 \right)^{7/4}}$$

> $$J_1 \equiv J_2$$

Mathematica confirms it numerically for $\gamma \in (-1,1)$. For $|\gamma|>1$ there's some trouble with computing the integrals numerically.

[image]

Moreover, as we see, both integrals follow linear dependence on $\gamma$ with very good accuracy.

Using linear regression in Mathematica, I obtained, with amazing accuracy the following fit:

> $$J_1(\gamma)= \frac{2}{3} L \gamma $$

Where $L$ is a lemniscate constant:

$$\frac{2}{3} L = \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{2 \pi}} \left( \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right)^2 =\frac{4}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$

Here are the plots with the proposed closed form (green) for comparison:

[image]

---

This gives us another task, to prove the proposed closed form for both integrals.

---

Note that for $J_1$ we can divide by $\gamma$ and obtain the following proposition:

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{ (1+\sin^2 x)  \cos^4 x~dx}{\left(\cos^4 x+(\gamma~ cos^2 x-\sin x)^2 \right)^{7/4}}=\frac{4}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$

Which makes $J_1/ \gamma$ yet another integral which doesn't depend on $\gamma$.

---

Edit, remark:

$^*$ this statement is not really stronger, because as we can see, the rest of the integrated function is non-negative for all $x$, which means that $J_1 \equiv J_2$ follows from $J \equiv 0$.

Comment: the trouble for $\lvert\gamma\rvert>1$ should be numeric instability as it is seen quite easily that the denominator is bounded away from 0, and therefore on that interval the integrand is a bonded continuous function.

Comment: I agree, I'll edit the part about diverging

Comment: Excuse me, why is $J_1=J_2$ stronger than $J=0$? It seems to me that the two things are exactly the same...

Comment: it gives you a non trivial identity, in that respect I think it should be considered stronger imho. However from the logical point of view you are right

Comment: You are right, it's not. I missed the part where the rest of the integrand is non-negative. I'll edit